# How do I implement a SYNC method in Angular, waiting for response, with no subscribe, like SYNC methods in C#?

Tags: javascript, angular, synchronization, angular7

How i could implement a method in 
Angular, with the same behavior as C#, as SYNC method, with no subscribe? The problem with subscribe is that my block of code need to be within the block, and i would like to write my code out of subscribe block.

My angular service method

```
public verifyExistingRegisterScheduled(workschedule: WorkSchedule) {
return  this.dataService.post<Result<any>>('/workschedule/existing-register-scheduled', workschedule);
```

}

My component code

```
this.workScheduleService.verifyExistingRegisterScheduled(this.workschedule)
  .subscribe(result => {
    if (result.content && result.content.length > 0) {
      result.content.forEach(register => {
```

I would like to do something like:

```
var return = this.workScheduleService.verifyExistingRegisterScheduled(this.workschedule);
```

return would wait to the end of the execute of the method verifyExistingRegisterScheduled

Comment: Is it only that you want to call methods from subscribe? .subscribe(success,failure); and the define the two method success and failure. I often do that

Comment: I would like to wait, a behavior similar to the server side process. There, by default is Sync. I would like the same behavior. I really don't understand how to implement this.

Comment: Hello again. Can you describe for my the context of why you want to wait( which I think would lock the browser)

Comment: For example. When you have one for in one method, and another for in another method, the second method need to wait the first method finish to go to the second method. This will lock the browser, right? It's the same, but i need to validate first, wait, and if the validation is correct, then i continue. That's pretty simple, but Angular and the unknowledge of the poeple make it veeeeeeery difficult.

Comment: You can chain methods in different ways. Either use rxjs which comes with Angular. This is a little bit trickier. Or you can just do you next server call inside the the subscribe block. Inside the block the first call has finished and you can start your next. This will chain them in order. And as I said earlier you can define functions is you feel like the block is getting messy

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Wasn't what I have asked.

Comment: So, you don't know the answer, and set up down arrow. Ok, it's you professional way. haha

Comment: I did not down arrow your question. I just up arrow It now. I still don’t fully understand what you want in the question.

Comment: It's simple : Make a Angular method SYNC.

Comment: Yes but in what purpose? The beauty of these browserside mvc is the async behavior. You mentioned that you wanted one server call to finish before the next start. And we can do that by chaining the calls. You can either call them parallel or you can chain. Or do you want to block the browser UI? Then why do you want to block the browser UI? You can easy hide/not render/disable any html part/elements that is not fully loaded. I'm asking this questions just to understand

Comment: I need to do a validation before to hide and show another div. In the "beauty way", i cannot do this, because he's showing the before to receive the answer fro the server. But is ok. I think nobody know this. Just to let you know, exists a property in XmlHTTPRequest exatcly for this, and by default, i don't know why, Angular pass true. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score -1):

```
public yourFunction(param: any):Promise<any>{
   let deferred: any = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
   // if you get data , you can also use setTimeout
   //resolve();
     setTimeout(()=>{
       //do something 
       resolve();
     });
   })
   return deferred;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply. Sorry buddy, I didn't understand. Where I put my URL? Where I receive the result?